# How to use Mermaid in Docusaurus version 3

Tags: docusaurus, mermaid

I updated docusaurus to latest version (3).[https://docusaurus.io/docs/migration/v3](https://stackoverflow.com) Hovewer mermaid plugin is not working there as expected. I followed  documentation [https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/diagrams](https://stackoverflow.com)

my docusaurus.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  markdown: {
    mermaid: true,
  },
  themes: ['@docusaurus/theme-mermaid'],
  ... rest of the code 
}
```

my .md file
[usage in .md file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A1dqF.png)

expected result [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRNKw.png)

got output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZfOY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with:

```
const config = {

  markdown: {
    mermaid: true,
  },
  themes: ['@docusaurus/theme-mermaid'],

... rest of the code

};
```